# Django date format issue using strptime().date

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm using django 1.8 in python 2.7

My code is

```
(datetime.strptime('diagnosis_circumstances_date', "%Y-%m-%d")).date()
```

and us a result I get `time data 'diagnosis_circumstances_date' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'`.

My date is `1980-08-28`.

Comment: Everything is in the documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the variable `diagnosis_circumstances_date`, not the string `'diagnosis_circumstances_date'`.

```
datetime.strptime(diagnosis_circumstances_date, "%Y-%m-%d")).date()
```

Comment: I'm using it as a string because I'm using it in `chartit` module.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention chartit anywhere. For the code you have posted, you must pass the date string `strptime`. Passing the name of a variable will simply not work.